# VScode img folder location

Tags: image, visual-studio-code, directory, location

Starting off with html and css and encountered one issue
while placing img folder in project file images doesn't appear in the browser and moved the img folder inside the css folder within the project and now it is viewing in the browser.

what is the correct place for img folder for the project is it has to be in css folder or in main project folder?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you're using absolute paths to reference your images, something like this :

- **"C:/Users/Jean/Desktop/Test/images/150x150.png"**

Use relative paths to your 'index.html':

- **"./images/150x150.png"**

About the place for the images folder, I think is good to have a basic structure like this :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer i will check it out

Answer (score 1):

If you have the image folder in the same directory as your html file, then reference that folder and then the image as a path.

*Example*: **src="./pictures/background.png"**